# BubbleSort CSV by specific column

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I've got a csv-file containing multiple rows and colums.
I want to use python and bubblesort to sort the file by a specific column.
For example:

Input csv-file:

> ```
> Daniel,New York,23456,Gaming
> Melinda,Washington,45678,Sports
> Dave,Chicago,12345,Hiking
> Ross,Boston,34567,Chess
> ```

Output:

> ```
> Dave,Chicago,12345,Hiking
> Daniel,New York,23456,Gaming
> Ross,Boston,34567,Chess
> Melinda,Washington,45678,Sports
> ```

In this example the rows should be sorted by the third column.

Until now i'm only able to sort the third column but the other columns stay in place.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Seack Overflow. Please see the [tour] and how to create a [mcve]: it's hard to help fix your code if you don't share the code (despite an exceedingly generous user writing a complete implementation below)...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using the python built-in csv module. This solution assumes that the input csv file is in test.csv, and you want the output in output.csv.

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r'))
rows = [row for row in file]


# Python program for implementation of Bubble Sort
# from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-bubble-sort/
# modified to sort by the third element in the row per SO question
def bubble_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    # Traverse through all array elements
    for i in range(n - 1):
        # range(n) also work but outer loop will repeat one time more than needed.
        # Last i elements are already in place
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1
            # Swap if the element found is greater
            # than the next element
            if arr[j][2] > arr[j + 1][2]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]

    return arr


sorted_rows = [', '.join(row)+'\n' for row in bubble_sort(rows)]
with open('output.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines(sorted_rows)
```

Note: you could also use pandas to read in the csv file, and sort using a faster built-in algorithm in pandas!