# Dictionary with dataframe as key value:

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dictionary with values as dataframe and keys as customer ID and i want to apply a bubble sorting on every price columns in these dataframe by making an iteration on keys in the dictionary. i got a keyerror 0 and don't know how to fix the error. The sorting is only make for the first key. Here is my bubble sorting code:

```
def tri_bulle(tab,s,h,o,d):

n = len(tab)
#boucle pour parcourir entièrement les lignes du dataframe
for i in range(n):
    #Initialisation du changement de position a false
    swapped = False
    #boucle pour la comparaison des éléments à chaque ligne 
    for j  in range(0,n-i-1):
        
        if tab[j]>tab[j+1]:
            
            if ((s[j] <= s[j+1]) and (h[j]<=h[j+1]) and (o[j]<=o[j+1]) and (d[j]<=d[j+1])):
                
                #permuter les positions si les conditions si haut sont tous réunies   
                tab[j],tab[j+1] = tab[j+1],tab[j]
                swapped = True
            
            if not swapped :
                break
        
return tab
```

Here is how my dictionary look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVYJ7.png)

When i try this cod below it's only work for the first key and i got a keyerror 0

```
tri = {}
```

for k in Restitution :

```
R = Restitution[k].price1
s = Restitution[k].SOINS
h = Restitution[k].HOSPI
o = Restitution[k].OPTIQUE
d = Restitution[k].DENTAIRE

tri [k] = tri_bulle(R,s,h,o,d)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=0)

pp.pprint(tri)
#print(R)
```

Can someone help me please?

here is how my dictionnary look like :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6K22.png)

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091063/bubblesort-csv-by-specific-column

Comment: Thanks! I try to fix it by using the same method but i got the same keyerror

Comment: share your traceback.

Comment: Sorry i fix it just by adding iloc to specify correctly the position of the columns in the bubble sorted code. Thanks by the way.